# Calling two forward modules asynchronously in parallel in PyTorch

Tags: parallel-processing, pytorch, gpu

I have to compute the output of two modules in parallel. There is no dependency between the two processing. Is it possible in PyTorch? I only need to do this during eval without batch processing.

My current code looks like this (`input1.shape[0] = 1` and `input2.shape[0] = 1`)

```
x = self.layer1(input1)
y = self.layer2(input2)
```

I am wondering if something like this is feasible -

```
x, y = call_in_parallel(self.layer1(input1), self.layer2(input2))
```

Note that I do not need this functionality for training the model. I only need it during the evaluation phase during which I process the inputs in a batch size of 1.

Plus, in my case, I do not have simple MLP layers. I will like to call separate forwards on more complex models like GNNs or transformers.

Comment: I think Pytorch computations on GPU are asynchronous by default. That should mean that `x` and `y` should be computed in parallel without any additional code. This [discussion](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/asynchronous-computation-on-cpu-while-training-on-cuda/126125) may be useful.

Comment: Thanks! After reading the thread it seems that asynchronous computation will be done while training. Is it also true during eval? I am guessing yes but I just wanted to get a confirmation.

Comment: As long as the code is running on GPUs, it should do async computations. Not sure about CPUs.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a direct way to verify this?

Comment: One very crude way to test this is to make two forward calls in series, and time each of them, once with synchronize call after each forward (case 1), and once without synchronize calls (case2). if your forwards consume fairly large runtime (a few ms), the hypothesis is that case 1 will show larger runtime for forward 1 (has wait for synchronization) as compared to case 2.

Comment: [this](https://gist.github.com/iacolippo/9611c6d9c7dfc469314baeb5a69e7e1b#file-measure-fp-bp-py-L11) is an example of synchronized time measuring for torch cuda.